# Run latest ASP.NET Core version on Google App Engine

Tags: asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform

I've been working on a .net core 2.0 web app recently and thought of using Google's App Engine on google cloud to host it, but as per the tutorial, google cloud uses .net core 1.0 which doesn't support my project.
Is there any way i can run app made using the newer sdk on the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy your application as self-contained application, then you can run it w/o a runtime installed.

It's well describe in the ASP.NET Core documentation [Self-contained deployment without third-party dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#simpleSelf)

It boils down to adding `<RuntimeIdentifier>` or `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` Elements to your csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and doing a `dotnet restore`, followed by a `dotnet build`.

Finally you can publish it to one of the platforms you defined above:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64
dotnet publish -c Release -r osx.10.11-x64
```

The self-deployment will download all files necessary from nuget, this includes the .NET Core runtime and put it into the output folder.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly the tutorial is out of date. We have runtime images for .NET Core 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0 now a days. We're going through our documentation and fixing it, but it takes a while.

From the instructions in this updated [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart) you will need to have a minimal app.yaml, something like:

```
env: flex
runtime: aspnetcore
```

Then, from the root of your project you run:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet publish -c Release
```

Copy the app.yaml to the output of the publish process, typically `bin\Release\netcore2.0\publish` and then deploy your app with:

```
gcloud beta app deploy bin\Release\netcore2.0\publish\app.yaml
```

This command will detect what version of .NET Core you are using and build the appropriate Docker image for you.

Note that the .NET Core support in App Engine Flexible is still in beta, we're working really hard to go to GA soon.

Answer (score 3):

### Part 1

Make sure you have the following two files

- app.yaml
- Dockerfile

with the contents shown below in the root of your project.

**app.yaml**

```
env: flex
runtime: custom
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM [DOCKER_IMAGE_URL]
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "[NAME_OF_PROJECT].dll"]
```

Remember to replace `[NAME_OF_PROJECT]` with the name of your project and `[DOCKER_IMAGE_URL]` with one of the URLs from here:

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-aspnet/

For example: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0` for ASP.NET Core 3.0

### Part 2

For the files we created in part 1 to be put into use, they need to be copied to the output/build directory when we run the build command.

This can be done by adding the following

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="app.yaml"   CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  <None Include="Dockerfile" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to your `.csproj` file.

Now when we run the build command, they will be copied to `./bin/Release/netcoreapp[VERSION]/publish` for the release build and `./bin/Debug/netcoreapp[VERSION]` for the debug build.

where `[VERSION]` is the ASP.NET Core version you are using.

### Part 3

From here, deploy using the Google Cloud SDK [as usual.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart)

---

Thanks to:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZRam__Bx6o
2. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/runtime
3. https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/
4. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/4-ways-you-can-deploy-an-aspnet-core-app-to-gcp